# Jquery's closest() slow's my app down when it doesn't find an element, how do I do the same query but faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, profiling, closest

I want to see if a element is sat inside another one, I do this a lot of times in my app like this:

```
is_inside_something: function(element){
    return element.closest(".something").length == 1
}
```

So I'm see if there's an parent called is returned for ".something"

The problem I've noticed webpages slowing down and when I take a look at the webkit profiler it's this bit of code that's doing it.

Is there a quicker way of saying:

```
"Does the class '.something" exist as a parent of this element at all?"
```

It seems that this is taking up so much memory because it goes up through the while dom of the page all the way up to the head every time it's called. Which is a lot in my case.

Comment: how your some html pls, how your `element` and `.something` look like...

Comment: You can try doing the 'closest' operation to an element you KNOW exists, and then do a find on that result to look for your class selector.

Comment: As to why it's slower when it doesn't exist, that's simply because it has to go all the way from your nested `element` up to the `html` element to see if the selector matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use pure javascript and limit the number of DOM climb-up iterations:

```
var ctr=0;
var is_in_something=function(element,steps){
    if(ctr<steps){
    if($(element.parentNode).hasClass(".something")){
        return true;
    }else{
        ctr++;
        return is_in_something(element.parentNode,steps);
    }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

is_in_something(document.getElementById("mydiv"),20);
```

The above code will try to check the 20 parents of "mydiv". 
It will return true if one of the parent has the class ".something". 
If after 20 iterations no such parent is found, then it will return false.

So, with this you can control the number of levels you want to climb-up the DOM and not having to reach the HEAD everytime.

Comment: this function would return boolean `true` or `false` based on his original question, and on the name of the function itself. just sayin.

Comment: Thanks. Revised the code so that it returns a boolean instead of the actual DOM object.

Comment: +1'd for recursion. you could get rid of the `ctr` var, and simply do `--steps` in your recursive call. your first comparison would then just be `if (steps > 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

There is also the "parents" function depending on your context I think it helps. Here is a performance test

http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/2